# Sort objects by count

Tags: powershell

I'm working with an api which where I get data with `Invoke-RestMethod`,
the data is converted into objects from json and I do the following.

```
$P = 0
$Store = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$Get = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://someurl/$P"

#each page i store in a variable until i get all pages
$Store.Add( $Get.Objects)

#then i output the results
write $Store | Format-Table Name, Adres -AutoSize

Name         Adres
-----        ------
A             A
B             B
C             C
C             D
C             E
D             F
D             G
D             H
A             I
C             J
```

How do I query the results so that I can get an overview of the names which are linked to the most adresses and then put into order.

```
Name         Adres
-----        ------
C             C
C             D
C             E
C             J
D             F
D             G
D             H
A             A
A             I
B             B
```

Comment: what you mean with top 5? I can't see a pattern here...

Comment: I changed my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to group the objects by their name, sort them using the group count and finally expand the group to get back the desired output:

```
 $Store | group name | sort Count -Descending | select -expand Group
```

Comment: I tried it with your test data which works. Can you share the URL with us?

Comment: Sorry I cannot, because it contains sensitive data, but i discovered my issue and after changing it your solution worked like a charm